# Adding a vector of dummy variables in logistic regression

Tags: r, vector, linear-regression, logistic-regression, dummy-variable

I am currently trying to conduct logistic regression where one of the variables is a vector of 32 dummy variables. Each dummy represents a type of crime. For example:

```
narcotics <- ifelse(train$PRIMARY.DESCRIPTION == "NARCOTICS", 1,0)
```

Then the vector is created:

```
crime.type <- c(narcotics, theft, other.offense, burglary, motor.vehicle.theft, battery, robbery, assault, criminal.damage, deceptive.practice, kidnapping, etc.)
```

The logistic model is as follows:

```
logit.mod.train <- lm(street1 ~ BEAT+WARD+X.COORDINATE+Y.COORDINATE+LATITUDE+LONGITUDE+crime.type, data = train, family = "binomial")
```

It's important to note that street1 is actually a dummy variable for the location of the crime being on the street. So the column is LOCATION.DESCRIPTION and the element is street.

```
street1 <- ifelse(train$LOCATION.DESCRIPTION == "STREET", 1,0).
```

It yields this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = street1 ~ BEAT + WARD + X.COORDINATE +  : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'crime.type')
```

I thought this would work because they are derived from the same data set and the dummies represent each unique element of one of the columns. When I input each dummy variable separately it's successful but I want to condense the regression and make it more efficient.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The error message says `variable lengths differ`. Maybe it is related to how you created `crime.type`.  Did you mean `crime.type <- cbind(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend for each type of crime to be its own predictor, you'll need to bind them to `train`, and then specify the variables in your `lm` formula.  (Actually for logit it should be `glm()`.)

For a more compact formula, subset `train` in the `data=` argument of `glm()` to include only your response variable and your intended design matrix. Then use `street1 ~ .` as your formula.

```
train <- cbind(train, narcotics, theft)I
model.vars <- c("narcotics", "theft", "street1")
logit.mod.train <- glm(street1 ~ ., data = train[,model.vars], family = "binomial")
```

More explanation:

Using `ifelse` as you've done produces a `1` or `0` for every element in `train`.
When you define `crime.type` as `narcotics` (which has the length of `train`) plus any additional elements, `crime.type` is longer than the number of rows in `train`.
Then you're asking `lm()` to process a lopsided design matrix, where one predictor (`crime.type`) has more elements in it than the other predictors.  That's why you're getting the error.

Here's a replication of the issue:

```
N <- 100
train <- data.frame(PRIMARY.DESCRIPTION=sample(c("A","B"), replace = T, size = N),
                    response = rbinom(n=N, prob=0.7, size=1))
dim(train) # 100  2

narcotics <- ifelse(train$PRIMARY.DESCRIPTION == "A", 1, 0) 
length(narcotics) # 100

theft <-  ifelse(train$PRIMARY.DESCRIPTION == "B", 1, 0)
length(theft) # 100

crime.type <- c(desc.A, desc.B)
length(crime.type) # 200

logit.mod.train <- glm(response ~ PRIMARY.DESCRIPTION+crime.type, data = train, family = "binomial")
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = response ~ PRIMARY.DESCRIPTION +  : 
>         variable lengths differ (found for 'crime.type')

Comment: Thanks for our response. I forgot to mention that street1 is actually a dummy variable for the location of the crime. So the column is LOCATION.DESCRIPTION and the element is street. So the code is:
street1 <- ifelse(train$LOCATION.DESCRIPTION == "STREET", 1,0). The code above did not work so it might have to do with this

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. Thanks!
Because street1 is a dummy variable, I excluded it from model.vars and it worked

Comment: Great!  If this solution helped you please mark it accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.